# Cannot invoke sqrt(double) on the primitive type double

Tags: java, math, sqrt

for some reason my code wont run i get the error "cannot invoke sqrt(double) on the primitive type double" thats the only error i get when i compile it so everything else doesn't cause an error except the Math.sqrt(math) line. Help?

```
public class Confused {

public static double average(int x, int y) {
double ave= (x+y)/2.0;
return ave;
}
public static double slope(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2){
double slope= (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
return slope; }

public static int difference(int x, int y) {
int diff=x-y;
return diff; }

public static int square(int x) {
int power1=(int)Math.pow(x, 2);
return power1;

}
 public static double distance (int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {
double Math= (square(difference(x2,x1))) + (square(difference(y2,y1)));
 double dist= Math.sqrt(Math);
return dist;

}

public static void main(String[] args) { 
  System.out.println(average(2,3));
  System.out.println(slope(1,2,3,4));
  System.out.println(difference(10,5));
  System.out.println(square(10));
  System.out.println(distance(2,3,6,8));

}

}
```

Comment: `Math` is a class in Java

Comment: For future questions, it would help if you removed the code that doesn't cause any problems (`average`, `slope`, `difference`, and `square`), and also copy and paste the error message you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double Math= (square(difference(x2,x1))) + (square(difference(y2,y1)));
double dist= Math.sqrt(Math);
```

You're creating a new variable `Math`, on the next line you refer to that new variable since it shadows the global class `Math`. So its trying to call `double.sqrt(double)`, which does not exist.

Comment: Why would you want to name a variable as Math. isn't that confusing and against coding convention?

Comment: @LakshithaRanasingha Definitely, but the question was why the code produced that specific error, not whether I would write the same code.

Answer (score 1):

You're [hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2) the built-in class `Math` by using it as a variable. You could do

```
double result = square(difference(x2, x1)) + square(difference(y2, y1));
return Math.sqrt(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, [`Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) is a class in Java, you cannot use this as an object variable. Instead use some other variable name:

```
double operation = (square(difference(x2,x1))) + (square(difference(y2,y1)));
double dist = Math.sqrt(operation);
```

Comment: `Math` is valid as a variable name, it just overwrites `java.lang.Math`.  That's why the assignment succeeds, but the next line is the one that causes the error.